# Libcurl OpenSSL not found

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2013, libcurl

This is extremely annoying. I've been trying to solve this for weeks...
I've successfully built libcurl with OpenSSL but this piece of code keeps returning false. I guess my last choice is to find a pre-built library (DLL Release - DLL OpenSSL).
Edit:
Forgot to add that I tried all the relevant solutions I could find and none of them worked. BTW this is for VS

```
curl_version_info_data * vinfo = curl_version_info(CURLVERSION_NOW);
if (vinfo->features & CURL_VERSION_SSL)
    MessageBoxA(0, "Yes", 0, 0);
else
    MessageBoxA(0, "No", 0, 0);
```

Comment: have you tried build library using cmake?

Comment: You should probably tell us the details of how you built it, since that is likely where the problem is.  You probably didn't tell libcurl's confgure script where to find openssl, or something like that.  For what it's worth, you might consider moving away from Visual Studio and instead use [MSYS2](http://msys2.github.io/) for this stuff.  MSYS2 comes with a [curl package](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/blob/master/mingw-w64-curl/PKGBUILD) that includes libcurl.

Comment: @Sergey No, I haven't tried that.

Comment: @David Grayson I built libcurl with the VS 2013 solution. If someone has pre-built libs they can link me that'd be nice.

Comment: The MSYS2 package has a prebuilt dll: http://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/REPOS/MINGW/i686/mingw-w64-i686-curl-7.42.0-2-any.pkg.tar.xz/download

Comment: @David Greyson But that's not usable within a VS project, is it? I should have mentioned that in my earlier posts.

Comment: In the past I was able to use a Visual Studio-compiled DLL from a MinGW program, so I think the two environments are likely to be compatible enough for this purpose. Still, I go back to my original suggestion of moving away from Visual Studio and just using MSYS2, gcc, and gdb for this stuff.  Or maybe you could do some digging in order to find out how to configure the libcurl Visual Studio project to use OpenSSL.  You'll have to see if it has any features for doing that, and how to activate those.  You might have to edit project configuration settings and header files; I don't know.

Comment: I've already activated the features for OpenSSL and it builds fine but it still says I don't have it. I can't move away from VS. That's why I'm asking for VS pre-built libcurl (with OpenSSL) libs

Comment: Nobody reading this has built libcurl with openssl libs for VS? The question is tagged with 'libcurl'. Can someone PLEASE link me theirs?

Answer (score 1):

Here the my step-by-step instruction how to build [Curl](https://github.com/bagder/curl) with [OpenSSL](http://openssl.org/source/) using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) and Visual Studio (any version)

Pre-requisites:

1. Installed Microsoft Visual Studio
2. Installed CMake
3. Build and install OpenSSL development libraries as described [here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/INSTALL.W64) (in my case I've installed it here C:\WORK\MSVC2013.64\openssl using perl Configure --prefix=C:\WORK\MSVC2013.64\openssl ...)

Step-by-step procedure:

```
git clone https://github.com/bagder/curl.git
cd curl
mkdir b.msvc
cd b.msvc
cmake .. -G"Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=C:\WORK\MSVC2013.64\openssl
```

When CMake runs, be sure that OpenSSL is found

> -- Found OpenSSL: C:/WORK/MSVC2013.64/openssl/lib/ssleay32.lib;C:/WORK/MSVC2013.
>   64/openssl/lib/libeay32.lib (found version "1.0.2a")

When all done without error, you'll find solution file CURL.sln which can be opened in Visual Studio or just build it with command

```
cmake --build . --config Release
```

Then check, if it was built with OpenSSL enabled

```
C:\WORK\GitHub\curl\b.msvc\src\Release>curl.exe --version
curl 7.42.0-DEV (Windows) libcurl/7.29.1-DEV OpenSSL/1.0.2a
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp
Features: NTLM SSL
```

Another thing - you can provide following option to cmake

> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX= < path to where you want install curl/libcurl >

Then

```
cmake --build . --config Release --target INSTALL
```

will install curl/libcurl to provided location

Hope this helps.